# I created a webview application in Android Studio 2023, but it displays a white screen on the phone

Tags: android, webview

I created a webview application in Android Studio 2023, but it displays a white screen on the phone. Javascript enabled and there is internet permission in manifest. why not working white page...
MainActivity.java :

```
package com.cmf.deneme;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.yen);

        // WebViewClient ekleyerek web sayfasını uygulamanızın içinde açın
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // İhtiyaca bağlı, JavaScript'i etkinleştirmek istiyorsanız

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/yen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
                android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
                android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Deneme"
                tools:targetApi="31">
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I tried everything for the app to work, but it still showed a white screen

Comment: i think you are missing the ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"``` in ```<Application>``` Tag. If still not work try adding ```android:networkSecurityConfig``` in ```Application``` Tag.

Comment: Where should I add it to which page?

Comment: and target api33

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example which you can consider for you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.web);

        // WebViewClient ekleyerek web sayfasını uygulamanızın içinde açın
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // İhtiyaca bağlı, JavaScript'i etkinleştirmek istiyorsanız

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Webview"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Actually You Did not understand the question what he is asking. He has asked me where to add it. so I have given example and its working for him and he has upvoted. what is the problem with you

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works for **secure** URLs like `https://` and **not** `http://`. If you want to load a **clear text** URL `http://`, you have to add a line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

after the "`<application`" tag in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

There is `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest,   and http or https not working.Other sites example google working. But there is many javascript in my website . mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.yen);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}
```

}

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
    android {
    namespace = "com.mara.erkan"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mara.erkan"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```